# SPOJ shows wrong answer to the my solution to: http://www.spoj.com/BSCPROG/problems/SMPCPH1/

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
    int n, m, i, j, k;
    char a[100], b[100];
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n > 26 && n <= 1)
        exit(0);
    scanf("%s", a);
    scanf("%d", &m);
    if (m > 100 && m <= 1)
        exit(0);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        fgets(b, 100, stdin);
        for (j = 0; b[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                if (a[k] == b[j]) {
                    if (k == (n - 1)) {
                        b[j] = a[0];
                        break;
                    } else {
                        b[j] = a[k+1];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%s",b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> I just have written C code for the problem: http://www.spoj.com/BSCPROG/problems/SMPCPH1/
>   With the given example my program gives desired result but spoj says it is wrong. How can I find mistakes?

Comment: Flagging to close this question as *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Comment: `if(n>26 && n<=1)` is always false as any number cannot be less than or = `1` and greater than `26` at the same time

Comment: When I run your code, it does not solve the examples. It outputs two lines correctly but there was no third line output.

Comment: ...or to give you a clue, the first line of the sample text is incorrectly read. The perils of mixing input methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need 3 changes in your code:

- Use `||` instead of `&&` in your argument validation tests.
- Scan and ignore the line feed after the number parsed into `m`, otherwise the next `fgets()` will read an empty line

Here is the corrected code:

```
if (n > 26 || n <= 1)
    exit(0);
scanf("%s", a);
scanf("%d%*c", &m);
if (m > 100 || m <= 1)
    exit(0);
```